# Listview not updating on inserting the item to database using cwac-loaderex

Tags: android, sql, cursor, commonsware-cwac

i'm using Sqliteloader by [commnsware](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) , this looks pretty simple because without help of content provider i'm able to use the loader functionality just by using simple SQL querys.

Now, on tapping on a button, i'm filling a form and insert the item to database like this.

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Tbldata.ACCOUNT, getActiveAccount());            
values.put(Tbldata.time, dateobj.getTime());

getWritableDatabase().insert('Tbldata', 'ACCOUNT', values);
```

After this call, i will be calling `finish()` on my activity and it returns to my listview. Here the listview item is not updated

What is the best way to update `listview`?, should i call requery like this?

```
mLoaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this);
```

is it correct way of doing?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to update listview?

Call `insert()` on the `SQLiteCursorLoader`, not on the `SQLiteDatabase`. Quoting [the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex#database-modifications):

> If you use the `insert()`, `update()`, `delete()`, `replace()`, and
>   `execSQL()` methods on `SQLiteCursorLoader`, the loader
>   framework will automatically update you to reflect a new
>   `Cursor` with the changed data. These methods take
>   the same parameters as they do on `SQLiteDatabase`.

Note that I am no longer maintaining `SQLiteCursorLoader`.